# $|\Delta f|^2$ in local coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

The Laplace-Beltrami in local coordinates (for hypersurfaces in my case) is
$$\Delta f = \frac{1}{\sqrt {|g|}} \partial_i \left(\sqrt{|g|} g^{ij} \partial_j f \right)$$
Is there a nice formula for its size:
$$|\Delta f|^2?$$
Can somebody tell me what it is? Differentiating using everything using product rule with multiple sums is confusing..

Comment: _Short answer_: **no**. _Longer comment_: why do you ask? "Nice" is not a mathematical concept, and it would be better if you can given some indication of the motivation that brought you to ask this question. At least it will guide potential respondents to what you consider "nice".

Comment: @Willie by nice I meant "expand by the product rule and do something non-trivial to it". I want it cause I want to differentiate the integral of that with respect to time.

Comment: If you're time-differentiating, why not use $(\Delta f)^2$, differentiate that, and then use that partials commute?

Comment: @Neal: if the hypersurface also evolves, then the partials _do not_ commute. Note that the OP is working on a Riemannian manifold.